# UPDATE column with VARCHAR(2) 4000 byte value

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, sql-types

I want to update a table with complex entries in a column and just a clause in the column without effecting other values.

Want to update `#Rule number=0#` to `#Rule number=1#` but without affecting other values in the column. Is this possible?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for `replace()`?  If `dynamic_attributes` is a string:

```
update t
    set dynamic_attributes = replace(dynamic_attributes,
                                     '#Rule number=0#',
                                     '#Rule number=1#'
                                     )
    where dynamic_attributes like '%#Rule number=0#%';
```

Note:  Strings may not be the best way to store such a list.  You should consider a table with one row per `customer_id` and dynamic attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
UPDATE A 
SET A.dynamic_attributes = REPLACE(A.dynamic_attributes,'#Rule number=0#','#Rule number=1#')  
FROM yourtable AS A  
WHERE A.dynamic_attributes LIKE '%#Rule number=0#%'
```